# Asp.Net MVC Razor markup for jQuery Mobile controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

This is an asp.net MVC mobile app - I have a From textbox, and a Nights text box - the standard view is:

```
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.From)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From)     
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.From)    
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nights)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nights)            
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nights)    
   </li>
```

What would I change the Razor markup above to add in data-options and data-role:

ie.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From)
```

to

```
<input name="From" type="date" data-options='{"mode":"datebox"}' data-role="datebox" id="From" />
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nights)
```

to

```
<input type="range" name="nights" id="nights" value="1" min="0" max="28" />
```

(these are a date plugin - and the slider control in Mobile)

**EDIT: I've got the second part:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nights, new { @type = "range", min = 1, max = 60 })
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for bothering everyone - I was knocking my heda against the wall, and then tried \ to get a quote inside a quote:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, new { @type = "date", data_role = "datebox", data_options = "{\"mode\":\"datebox\"}"})
```

The replacement for my original Razor markup is:

```
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.From)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.From, new { @type = "date", data_role = "datebox", data_options = "{\"mode\":\"datebox\"}"})    
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.From)    
    </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nights)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nights, new { @type = "range", min = 1, max = 60 })            
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nights)    
   </li>
```

Hope this is useful to others like me!!

Mark